# string iterators are incompatible

Tags: c++, stl

Here is my sample code ..

```
    const std::string strSchemeEnd("://");

    StringConstIteratorType itScheme = std::search(p_strUrl.begin(), p_strUrl.end(), strSchemeEnd.begin(), strSchemeEnd.end());
    StringConstIteratorType  l_itTempConst = p_strUrl.begin();
    m_strScheme.reserve(std::distance(l_itTempConst, itScheme));
    std::copy(l_itTempConst , itScheme, std::back_inserter(m_strScheme));
    boost::algorithm::to_lower(m_strScheme);
    l_itTempConst = strSchemeEnd.end();
    if ( itScheme == l_itTempConst )
        return;
```

When I try to run the program, I find the following errors

```
#if _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2
    void _Compat(const _Myiter& _Right) const
        {   // test for compatible iterator pair
        if (this->_Getcont() == 0
            || this->_Getcont() != _Right._Getcont())
            {   // report error
            _DEBUG_ERROR("string iterators incompatible");
            _SCL_SECURE_INVALID_ARGUMENT;
            }
        }
```

I face this problem a lot. Sometimes a workaround works and sometimes it doesn't. I want to know the cause of this "string iterators incompatible" error. Can somebody help me ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem in this case is that `itScheme` is an iterator pointing to `p_strUrl` and `l_itTempConst` is an iterator pointing to `strSchemeEnd`. Because they are pointing at different strings it is not legal to compare these two iterators.

Answer (score 4):

itScheme is an iterator into string p_strUrl
l_itTempConst isn an iterator into strSchemeEnd

You cannot compare iterators from different containers